# External mixer behringer talking while playing a song

Tags: sound-card, playback, mixer, volume-mixer

I bought [Behringer XENYX  1204usb](http://www.behringer.com/EN/Products/2442FX.aspx) mixer and I have problem. How to talk in the mic while playing a song? I did too much searching for this issue nothing I found helps.

I connect the mixer to the computer via USB and a vocal microphone connect in the mixer. I have windows 7 I have internal soundcard speakers (Realtek High Definition Audio) which is inside the computer.

I don't know if i miss cables or something

Comment: What exactly is the problem? That you're talking into the microphone, but can't hear yourself from the speakers? What application are you using to record and play audio? Can you see any indication of an incoming signal in that application? What microphone do you have? How are the speakers connected (to the computer or the mixer)?

Answer (score 1):

So many things.

1) Add headphones to the mixer - does any sound come out when you're singing/talking?
2) Is the device fully installed and recognized by Device manager with not error (and drivers up to date).
3) Some desks 'default' to mute and you have to arm them before any sound comes out.
4) Is the gain high enough. If the gain PAD is on it will reduce the gain?
5) Does your microphone require phantom power?
6) Are you using a jack cable or XLR? If jack, then it may 'see' (hear) it as an instrument and therefore the gain will not be high enough.
7) Are you trying to hear yourself live, or will it not record you.